# Session variable not passing from log in script

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am trying to pass a session variable from the log in script to display a Welcome [Username] massage, at the moment its not passing it through - any ideas? I am quite new to PHP so all your comments are greatly appreciated.

The code is as follows.

```
<?php
ob_start(); // Start output buffering

session_start(); //must call session_start before using any $_SESSION variables
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

function validateUser()
{

    session_regenerate_id (); //this is a security measure
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}

      $username = isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:'';
     $password = isset($_POST['password'])?$_POST['password']:'';

//connect to the database here

$hostname_PropSuite = "localhost";
$database_PropSuite = "propsuite";
$username_PropSuite = "root";
$password_PropSuite = "root";
$PropSuite = mysql_pconnect($hostname_PropSuite, $username_PropSuite, $password_PropSuite) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
mysql_select_db($database_PropSuite, $PropSuite);

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$query = "SELECT password, salt FROM admin_users WHERE username = '$username';";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such user exists
{
    header('Location: http://localhost/PropSuite/index.php?login=fail');

    die();
}
$userData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );
if($hash != $userData['password']) //incorrect password
{
    header('Location: http://localhost/PropSuite/index.php?login=fail');

    die();
}
else
{
   validateUser(); //sets the session data for this user
}
//redirect to another page or display "login success" message
header('Location: http://localhost/PropSuite/main');
die();




//redirect to another page or display "login success" message


?>
```

Comment: I dont see any "welcome" message in your code.

Comment: Its on the redirect page

Comment: paste the code for that also..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add username as parameter in the function

```
function validateUser($username)
{
    session_regenerate_id (); //this is a security measure
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}
```

And pass it when you call it

```
validateUser($username); //sets the session data for this user
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that your problem is that you are using `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` before $username is defined. `$username = isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:'';` needs to be above `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`.

Answer (score 1):

To access a variable declared in the global scope, from within a function, you have to use `global` keyword, like so:

```
function validateUser()
{
    global $username;//NEEDED to access $username declared in global scope
    session_regenerate_id (); //this is a security measure
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}
```

Comment: True but the better option is to pass it in as a parameter as [air4x suggests in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13073580/215966)

Comment: @prodigitalson yes, that is better and recommended practice. I just went the direct route to fix OP's current code without taking into account any refactoring, air4x is a more complete answer.